# Graph Theory Program

Tags: java

So right now i'm in a class learning graph theory. I thought it would be cool to make a program for it. To create different graphs, add and deleted nodes, edges and all the sort like that.

This semester I do not have no programming classes, so I'm trying to get ready for next semester when they start up again.

So far what I have is a Class called Graph Theory (Driver/Command-line) which of course runs the whole program.

Besides the driver class the main classes I have are: 
--Graph: TYPES: Path, Cycle, Complete...

Because they all have lists of nodes and edges and add/deleted methods in common I made the TYPES, like path and cycle, inherit from graph so I didn't have to remake those million methods for each one.

In the driver class I have a list of all created graphs.

```
ArrayList<Graph> graphs = new ArrayList<Graph>();
```

My problem is when I started working on the Partite graph class it inherits from Graph like the others, but I can't access the methods.

I the driver when i create the Partite:

```
Partite p = new Partite(blah, blah);
graphs.add(p);
```

When I go through and get this graph from the list I can't access the methods from Partite.
How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you get elements from `graphs` they will be references of type `Graph`.

To access the methods from `Partite` you must add a cast to `Partite`.

```
Partite p = new Partite(blah, blah);
graphs.add(p);
Partite other = (Partite)graphs.get(0);
other.methodFromPartite();
```

Done.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I had to cast it but I was just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

#### Basic solution

If you rely on specific `Partite` methods (as opposed to `Partite`'s versions of `Graph`'s methods) you shouldn't really be holding it in an array of `Graph`s but if you must you can cast

```
Graph g=graphs.get(i);
Partite p=(Partite)g;
```

Be aware that if you get it wrong (attempt to cast something that isn't a `Partite`) you will get an exception. You can check in advance if the cast is acceptable by using instanceof

```
if (g instanceof Partite){
   .....
}
```

#### A better concept

But as I say all this is usually a sign of bad program design. A better design would be to have only general graph behaviour triggered from reading this list (`Partite`s would still be in the list, but they would behave as `Graphs`) and a seperate list of `Partite`s being held as well for whatever different behaviour they need

#### An even better concept

If you can organise your program in such a way that you are only calling methods from `Graph` but `Parties` overrides some of them such that it behaves the way you want that is the ideal solution.

For example `Graph` has update and `Partite`s` overrides update to do the extra work it needs as well. So

```
public class Graph {


    public void update(){
        doImportantWork();
    }

}

public class Partite extends Graph{

    @Override
    public void update() {
        super.update(); //so that the basic graph behavior happens
        doPartiteSpecificImportantWork();
    }

}
```

This is not always practical however.

Comment: Well, the way I have it is; Graphs have edges, nodes, components, and such like that, but Partite graphs have sets of nodes, something other graph types do not. So the methods I made inside the Partite class was to add or delete one of these sets. 

How would you suggest I do this with overriding.

Comment: Right now i'm trying to find other ways to do this, so I have another project made where all graphs will just be created inside the Graph class and I won't have to worry about subClasses inheriting from it and accessing the other methods because right now the only real reason i have subclasses is because the creation of each graph is different. This was actually going to be my original question was if inheritance was the best way to make this program, if so then I asked how to access the inheriting classes methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're trying to modify your Partite object using a Graph reference to it. If you want to call sub class specific methods using parent class references, your design probably needs some modification (**this is a code smell**). To temporarily get around it for now you can case your Graph reference to a Partite reference.

```
((Partite)graphRef).[some method on partite]
```